# java swing borderlayout constraints error

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout, border-layout

I am new to Java *Swing* and I have been trying to create a vertical menu panel but I having been facing trouble in adding it to the left middle of the frame. I have a little knowledge on the layout packages provided by *Swing* and tried many ways to resolve this issue yet failed to fix it.

Here's the code I tried:

```java
this.mainPanel = new JPanel();

// Set up the button panel
JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
buttonPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(buttonPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

// Set a border for the button panel using a TitledBorder
TitledBorder border = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Menu");
buttonPanel.setBorder(border);

// Create three buttons with different text
this.homeMenuButton = new JButton("Home");
this.DoctorMenuButton = new JButton("Doctors");
this.ConsultationsMenuButton = new JButton("Consultations");
this.notesMenuButton = new JButton("Notes");
this.viewConsultationsMenuButton = new JButton("View Consultations");

buttonPanel.add(homeMenuButton);
buttonPanel.add(DoctorMenuButton);
buttonPanel.add(ConsultationsMenuButton);
buttonPanel.add(notesMenuButton);
buttonPanel.add(viewConsultationsMenuButton);

GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(buttonPanel);
buttonPanel.setLayout(layout);

layout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
layout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);

layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(homeMenuButton)
                .addComponent(DoctorMenuButton)
                .addComponent(ConsultationsMenuButton)
                .addComponent(notesMenuButton)
                .addComponent(viewConsultationsMenuButton)
);

layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(homeMenuButton)
                .addComponent(DoctorMenuButton)
                .addComponent(ConsultationsMenuButton)
                .addComponent(notesMenuButton)
                .addComponent(viewConsultationsMenuButton)
);

GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 0;
gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
mainPanel.add(buttonPanel, gbc);
```

I tried adding `BorderLayout` "west" constraint and failed.

Comment: Your question could be / should be more complete. You're using GridBagConstraints to add a component to the mainPanel but you don't show or tell what layout it is using. Is it using a GridBagLayout? If so, then the use of this constraint may be appropriate, but if not, then it isn't. Please post a decent [mre] with your question, making it easier to answer and more helpful to future visitors. Also, tell more of the pertinent details of your problem as per the [ask] links.

Comment: `GroupLayout` is not meant for a human to use.  Each `JPanel` should have its own Swing layout and your `JFrame` can use its default `BorderLayout` to place the `JPanels`.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) section.